# Time and space complexity of c++ program

Tags: c++, time-complexity, space-complexity

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

vector <int> removeFirstOrder(const vector<int>& orders)
{
    return vector<int>(++orders.begin() , orders.end());
}

bool isFirstComeFirstServed(const vector<int>& takeOutOrders,
                            const vector<int>& dineInOrders,
                            const vector<int>& servedOrders)
{
    //base case
    if(servedOrders.empty())
    {
        return true;
    }

    if(!takeOutOrders.empty() && takeOutOrders[0]==servedOrders[0])
    {
        return isFirstComeFirstServed(removeFirstOrder(takeOutOrders),
                                      dineInOrders,removeFirstOrder(servedOrders));

    }

    else if(!dineInOrders.empty() && dineInOrders[0]==servedOrders[0])
    {
        return isFirstComeFirstServed(takeOutOrders, removeFirstOrder(takeOutOrders),
                                        removeFirstOrder(servedOrders));

    }

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}


int main()
{
    vector<int> takeOutOrders{17,8,4};

    vector<int> dineInOrders{12,19,2};
    vector<int> servedOrders{17,8,12,19,24,2};
    isFirstComeFirstServed(takeOutOrders,dineInOrders,servedOrders);



    return 0;
}
```

My doubt is that here Author of this program says that it has O(n^2) time complexity and O(n^2) space complexity.

I agree with time complexity of this program because isFirstComeFirstServed function will be called n times which is size of servedOrders Vector Right? and removeFirstOrder will be call n times in first function call of isFirstComeFirstServed and n-1 times in second function call of isFirstComeFirstServed and so on till there are no element left in servedOrder Vector Right ?

But my doubt is that how it can O(n^2) space complexity? can someone help me to visualize it ?

Comment: At a glance is it O(n) (linear) in time. Each call creates a vector that is one element smaller so stack space n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 0 = n(n+1)/2 which is O(n^2) in space. Of course there is no need to retain the original vector since it is tail recursive so all these don't need to be save and should be freed so it really should be O(n) space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time `removeFirstOrder` is called the returned vector is smaller by 1.

```
n-1 + n-2 + n-3 + ... + 1
```

From [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) rules, the sum is (n+1)*n / 2 which is order n^2.

[Tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) optimization could make it O(n) space behind the scene, but it's not guaranteed be performed at all.

Comment: Of course if tail call optimization is used the original vectors will be deallocated and it is reduced to O(n).

Comment: is it like it create new vector of the size that you mentioned right? It isn't size of stack calls right ?

Comment: @wcochran I was about to make an edit, gcc doesn't promise to do tail call optimization anyway. can't assume that.

Comment: @TonyTannous yep -- sort of depends on what the compiler / RTS does. I would bet that llvm -O3 would optimize it it to simple linear.

Comment: @SanjayVerma the stack is where these vectors are getting stored (assume no tail call optimization) -- the internals are stored on the heap -- anyway -- somewhere in memory.

Comment: Okay yes great! Thanks i will try to modify the program so that it should take constant time.

Comment: @SanjayVerma I think you mean linear time :) I think the compiler will (should) do it for you if optimization is used.

Comment: No sir i mean O(1) time.